# Trigger a popup in Windows from Java

Tags: java, windows, popup

I have a 2 machine setup. Each machine has its own jboss running as a service, There are times when I make a URL connection from one machine to application on the other. Some times the jboss service is not running. This causes the connection to fail. Is there a way I can trigger a popup message to the user on the other machine in case of connection failure? So the service can be started. It would be good if i could do it from my java side itself.

Both the machines are in the same network.

Comment: I do not know the user. I just know the IP.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Java can only popup a window if it's running on the computer, and by definition in this case it's not. Maybe try asking on Super User or Server Fault?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("msg Console /SERVER:OTHERSERVER \"Please restart JBoss service!\"");
```

Altough I have to admit to not have tested that from code run as service...

Comment: I have kept that as a last option. Is there any other way?

Comment: As the service on the other side is down you don't have "anything" running there. So you're stuck with what you have on the local machine - which is Windows. Building yet another (self-restarting?) service just to monitor for "please restart" messages seems to be a bit too much